# pgfmathmin and pgfmathsetmacro and array

Tags: arrays, pgfmath, pgfmathparse

I am trying to calculate the minimum and maximum of an array. The only problem unsolved is to save the value in a macro/variable.

```
\documentclass[utf8,fleqn]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}


\begin{document}


\def\myarray{{3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11}}


\pgfmathmin{(\myarray)}{} \pgfmathresult

%\pgfmathsetmacro{\minim}{min(\myarray)} %does not work

%\pgfmathsetmacro{\minim}{min{\myarray}} %does not work

%\pgfmathsetmacro{\minim}{min({\myarray})} %does not work

%\pgfmathsetmacro{\minim}{min{(\myarray)}} %does not work

\end{document}
```

Can anyone help please? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```latex
\expandafter\pgfmathmin\myarray{}
```

Then `\pgfmathresult` is set to `3.0`